# For update operation,average amount is not updating in apex trigger

Tags: apex, after-trigger, update, after

Trigger scenario:

__    .
      ,
           .

My implementation:

```
trigger oppTrigger on Opportunity(after insert, after update) {
  switch on Trigger.OperationType {
    when AFTER_INSERT, AFTER_UPDATE {
      oppHandler.averageCalculation(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
  }
}
```

Handler class:

```
  public static void averageCalculation(
    List<Opportunity> oppList,
    Map<Id, Opportunity> mapoldOpp
  ) {
    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();

    Map<Id, Decimal> getaverageAmt = new Map<Id, Decimal>();

    List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();

    for (Opportunity opp : oppList) {
      if (mapoldOpp != null) {
        system.debug('1st::');
        if (
          mapoldOpp.get(opp.AccountId) != null &&
          mapoldOpp.get(opp.AccountId).Amount != opp.Amount
        ) {
          accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
      } else {
        accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
      }
    }

    if (!accIds.isEmpty()) {
      List<AggregateResult> agResult = [
        SELECT AccountId, AVG(Amount) avgAmount
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE AccountId IN :accIds
        GROUP BY AccountId
      ];

      for (AggregateResult ag : agResult) {
        getaverageAmt.put(
          (Id) ag.get('AccountId'),
          (Decimal) ag.get('avgAmount')
        );
      }

      for (Id accId : getaverageAmt.keySet()) {
        accToUpdate.add(
          new Account(
            Id = accId,
            OpportunityAverageAmount__c = getaverageAmt.get(accId)
          )
        );
      }

      if (!accToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update accToUpdate;
      }
    }
  }
```

For example, I have two Opportunity amounts related to an Account. The first Opportunity's amount is 1500, and the second Opportunity's amount is also 1500. After an insert operation, I'm getting an average result of 1500. However, when I change either one of the Opportunity amounts, the average is not recalculated. What could be the issue, and what workaround should I implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, if you were doing this for real, you'd just use a [Rollup Summary Field](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US&type=5). Or, for some reason, if you couldn't do that, you should consider [DLRS](https://install.salesforce.org/products/dlrs/latest) as an alternative. As to why your code isn't working, it's hard to tell.

A more appropriate solution is to check to see if the account average has changed, and if so, update the account. Here's a reference implementation:

```
  public static void updateAverages(
    Opportunity[] triggerOld,
    Opportunity[] triggerNew
  ) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    // Get Account Ids
    if (triggerOld != null) {
      for (Opportunity opportunity : triggerOld) {
        accountIds.add(opportunity.AccountId);
      }
    }
    if (triggerNew != null) {
      for (Opportunity opportunity : triggerNew) {
        accountIds.add(opportunity.AccountId);
      }
    }
    // Default to sum of zero
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for (Id accountId : accountIds) {
      accounts.put(
        accountId,
        new Account(Id = accountId, OpportunityAverageAmount__c = 0)
      );
    }
    // Getting existing values
    Map<Id, Account> existingAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
      [SELECT OpportunityAverageAmount__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]
    );
    Account[] updatedAccounts = new Account[0];
    // Get sums for each account
    for (AggregateResult result : [
      SELECT AVG(Amount) avg, AccountId AccountId
      FROM Opportunity
      WHERE Id IN :accountIds
      GROUP BY AccountId
    ]) {
      Account summedAccount = accounts.remove((Id) result.get('AccountId'));
      summedAccount.OpportunityAverageAmount__c = (Decimal) result.get('avg');
      updatedAccounts.add(summedAccount);
    }
    // These accounts had a zero sum
    updatedAccounts.addAll(accounts.values());
    // Don't update records that haven't changed
    // We go from top to bottom so we don't miss accounts
    for(Integer index = updatedAccounts.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
      if(updatedAccounts[index].OpportunityAverageAmount__c == existingAccounts.get(updatedAccounts[index].Id).OpportunityAverageAmount__c) {
        updatedAccounts.remove(index);
      }
    }
    // Note: an empty list doesn't use governor limits.
    update updatedAccounts;
  }
```

Comment: if(mapoldOpp!=null && mapoldOpp.get(opp.AccountId)!=null)
{
   if(mapoldOpp.get(opp.AccountId).Amount!=opp.Amount)
     {                    
          accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
                    
     }
                    
                
}

Comment: I just changed the code like this  and it worked well. Anyway thanks for help sfdcfox.